# I want to create mutiple turtles in newly created class

Tags: python, class, turtle-graphics

I am given a problem where I have to create a simple object-oriented code that creates two turtles moving in opposite directions, but with my trial I am faced with unknown errors

I tried to initialize two variables `turtle1` and `turtle2` with `self` because I inherited `Turtle` and s

```
from turtle import *
class moveOpposite(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setx=0
        self.sety=0
    def move(self):
        turtle1=self
        turtle2=self
        turtle1.forward(100)
        turtle2.forward(-100)


my_turtle=moveOpposite()
my_turtle.move()
```

I didn't use `self._go` but my error says I did like this:

```
self._go(distance)
```

I also didn't use `self._position` and etc but it also says I did and gives me an `AttributeError`

```
ende = self._position + self._orient * distance
AttributeError: 'moveOpposite' object has no attribute '_position'
```

Comment: After `turtle1=self` and `turtle2=self`, you now simply have three names for a single turtle object - you haven't actually *created* anything.  And instances of your `moveOpposite` class aren't valid `Turtle`s anyway, because your `__init__()` doesn't call the inherited `__init__()`, which performs all sorts of necessary initializations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't inherit from `Turtle`, i.e. ***isa***, in this situation as your object isn't a turtle but a pair of them.  I'd go with the ***contains*** approach instead:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Zax():  # a la Dr. Suess
    def __init__(self):
        self.east_bound = Turtle('turtle')
        self.west_bound = Turtle('turtle')
        self.west_bound.setheading(180)

    def forward(self, distance):
        self.east_bound.forward(distance)
        self.west_bound.forward(distance)

    def right(self, angle):
        self.east_bound.right(angle)
        self.west_bound.right(angle)

    def left(self, angle):
        self.east_bound.left(angle)
        self.west_bound.left(angle)

screen = Screen()

zaxen = Zax()
zaxen.forward(100)

for _ in range(4):
    zaxen.forward(20)
    zaxen.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]